# make permanent virtual interface?

Tags: linux, networking, centos

I want to have two IPs sharing the same interface and it's just working fine by creating a virtual interface using the following command (`eth0` is my original interface):

```
ifconfig eth0:0 <someip> netmask <somenetmask>
```

It works fine and I can see it using `ifconfig` until I restart the system.
So, I did create `ifcfg-eth0:0` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` with this content:

```
DEVICE=eth0:0
IPADDR=<some ip>
NETMASK=<some netmask>
ONBOOT=yes
```

However, when I put this virtual interface up, it overwrites the original interface and when I put original interface up, it overwrites the virtual interface. I just can't use both at the same time when I'm using the permanent way.

P.S.: I use the following commands to put interface up:

```
# To make up    
ifup eth0 
ifup eth0:0
```

I'm using cent-OS

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate that problem with Centos.
Have you tried **eth0:1** instead of **eth0:0**?
Also, I noticed that **ifup eth0** brings up all virtual interfaces, so you don't need to **ifup eth0:1**.

Tested with Centos 6.4.

Comment: i'm using it under virtual box i think the problem is somehow related to that

Comment: I'm also running it in virtual box

Comment: What happens, if you rename ifcfg-eth0:0 to `ifcfg-myname`? Will ifup eth0 sill bring up eth0:0?

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps that I generally follow to create a virtual interface (aka. network alias) on Red hat based distros:

1. create network config file

   ```
   $ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:0
   TYPE=Ethernet
   DEVICE=eth0:0
   IPADDR=192.168.1.2
   NETMASK=255.255.255.0
   NETWORK=192.168.1.0
   BROADCAST=192.168.1.255
   ONBOOT=yes
   NAME=eth0:0
   BOOTPROTO=none
   USERCTL=no
   IPV6INIT=no
   ONPARENT=yes
   PEERDNS=yes
   ```
2. remove `GATEWAY=` lines from base ifcfg file:

   ```
   $ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
   TYPE=Ethernet
   DEVICE=eth0
   IPADDR=192.168.1.1
   NETMASK=255.255.255.0
   NETWORK=192.168.1.0
   BROADCAST=192.168.1.255
   ONBOOT=yes
   NAME=eth0
   BOOTPROTO=none
   USERCTL=no
   IPV6INIT=no
   ONPARENT=yes
   PEERDNS=yes
   ```
3. add `GATEWAY=` line to network config file:

   ```
   $ cat /etc/sysconfig/network
   HOSTNAME=grinchy
   NETWORKING=yes
   GATEWAY=192.168.1.254
   ```
4. start networking

   ```
   # start just eth0:0
   $ ifup eth0:0

   # all networking
   $ /etc/init.d/networking restart
   ```

#### References

- [13.2. Interface Configuration Files - Deployment Guide CentOS 5.x](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html)